# How to add xml files into the assembly using Pre or Post build event in VS.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, build, embedded-resource

I have a web application project and some .xml file are present in one of the folders i.e. \ProjectXMen\xml\files. I cannot include this folder into the project because these files are made dynamically. So i need to find a way where these files can be made to generate resource (.resx )files. And i guess we can do something with Pre or Post build event from vs.net IDE.

Now i want to convert these xml files into resource .resx files and finally add them to the project assembly.

Please suggest.

Comment: Not sure why you can't add dynamically generated files into the project? Remember all designer files (`designer.cs`) - they are also dynamic! What exactly is xml files' content?

Comment: XML file is having the Microsoft ResX Schema for the key-value pairs of strings that needs to be translated.

Comment: If xml files have the same schema as ResX then you can simply rename them as .resx - what is need of conversion? I am sorry but I don't understand your problem - who generate these xml files? Does number of files and their name varies on each generation?